# Least angle regression packages for R or MATLAB

Tags: r, classification, matlab, lars

I am looking for a Least Angle Regression (LAR) packages in R or MATLAB which can be used for **classification** problems.

The only package that I currently know which fits this description is [glmpath](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmpath/index.html). The issue with this package is that it is a little old and somewhat limited in its scope (I am forced to rely on logistic regression for classification problems model).

I am wondering if anyone knows of other packages that allow me to run LAR on different types of classification models, such as Support Vector Machines (see [The Entire Regularization Path for the Support Vector Machine](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.391&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

The ideal package would allow me to run LAR-type algorithms for different types of classification models and also provide a function that can produce the full regularization path.

Comment: I just saw that The Entire Regularization Path for the Support Vector Machine paper also refers to an R package named 'svmpath'. This answers some of my question, but any other packages that you guys know about would be very helpful.

Comment: GLMNET is another R package

Comment: The package `LARS` in R. I wondered why it wouldn't turn up on a google search of say 'least angle regression in R'... but for me it's the top result. Did you not google?

Comment: @Glen_b I did, and it did turn up, but as far as I know the LARS package only handles regression problems and not classification problems - right?

Comment: My apologies. Well of course regression *can* be used for classification, but that's not what you mean.

Comment: @probabilityislogic FYI if you want to submit an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it! GLMNET is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: You do realise glmnet only fits logistic/softmax classification?

Answer (score 2):

For those that might run into this, there is the [SpaSM toolbox](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/projects/spasm/) for matlab. It includes LAR and other methods of relevance. Otherwise there is also the [Glmnet for matlab](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_matlab/) and the R version, they use coordinate descent (*at least in the matlab version*).